# TypeError: init is not a function at mountReducer

Tags: html, reactjs, web-frontend, react-context

I am trying to use ContextAPI so i started off with making the file :
*Just before including these files everything worked and now the app has just crashed and isnt working at all.*

StateProvider.js

```
// setting up the data layer in order to have record of the basket and then use it in and keep track of user
// need to track basket
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

// This is the data layer
const StateContext = createContext();
export { StateContext };

// build a provider
const StateProvider = ({ reducer, intialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, intialState, children)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export { StateProvider };

// THIS IS HOW WE USE IT IN THE COMPONENT
const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
export { useStateValue };

// Then created a file reducer.js :
reducer.js;

export const intialState = {
  basket: [],
};

//

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      //    Logic for adding
      break;

    case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET':
      // lOGIC for removing item from basket
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aqFJ.png) is an image of the error log.